# Someone marked my question as duplicate but it is not

Tags: discussion

A post of mine has been marked as a duplicate. The moderator who marked it posted a link to a different (but similar) question. I edited my question to specify the differences, but my post still shows up with duplicate after the name. Do I need to completely re-ask the question?

Answer (score 1):

When you edit a closed question, a poll for reopening it starts automatically.

This gives the community members a chance to see if your question now is different enough from the question that it was marked a duplicate of. If so, they vote for a reopening and your question, in time, gets reopened